# How to paste value when copying formatted text in TextBox

Tags: xaml, text, windows-10, uwp, paste

I have a TextBox in a Windows 10 UWP Application that looks like this.

```
<TextBox Name="QuoteBox" 
                     MinHeight="160"  
                     TextAlignment="Left" 
                     TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                     Margin="12"
                     RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True" 
                     RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" 
                     RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                     IsTabStop="True" KeyDown="InputBox_KeyDown" 
                     Height="{x:Bind MainScrollViewer.ViewportHeight, Converter={StaticResource TwoFifthsConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

What I'm trying to do is copy / paste some text in this TextBox. The issue is that when I copy text from an e-mail, website or even OneNote, the text isn't pasted.

But when I paste that text in Notepad, and copy it from there to the TextBox, it works.

I assume this is because the text contains formatting and TextBox doesn't support pasting formatting text.

There were many questions like this, but they were concerning very specific solutions and custom Paste event handlers.

How can you paste text from within formatted text in a TextBox? Does it need a custom Paste event handler?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue. I can copy form Mail, Edge and OneNote and paste into TextBox. I'd suggest you create a blank project with only one TextBox to test again.

Comment: That's interesting, have you tried copying formatted text into Wunderlist UWP app? It has the same issue. Managed to find a solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I created an event handler for the Paste event. Basically what I did was just copy the text from the clipboard to the textbox Text property.

It is a simplification of the example found in the Paste event handler [documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.paste.aspx)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Used to paste text when copying formatted text
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private async void QuoteBox_Paste(object sender, TextControlPasteEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox quoteBox = sender as TextBox;
        if (quoteBox != null)
        {
            // Mark the event as handled first. Otherwise, the
            // default paste action will happen, then the custom paste
            // action, and the user will see the text box content change.
            e.Handled = true;

            // Get content from the clipboard.
            DataPackageView dataPackageView = Clipboard.GetContent();
            if(dataPackageView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text))
            {
                try
                {
                    // Copy text from the clipboard
                    quoteBox.Text = await dataPackageView.GetTextAsync();
                }
                catch
                {
                    // Ignore exception
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When using a RichEditBox, you can use the `MyRichEditBox.Document.Selection.TypeText` method to easily insert text at the current position